# a Direct computation of infinitesimal generator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

Could anyone show me a way to directly compute the generator of a strongly continuous semigroup $S(t)$ in $L^p$
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{S(t)f-f}{t}$$
where the limit shall lies in $L^p$
Here $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$,
and on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $p\in [1,\infty)$, we have the expression 
$$(S(t)f)(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(y)e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}}dy\right)$$

I meant to start with  $\frac{d}{dt}\int f(y)n_t(x-y)dy$ and make use of   $\frac{d}{dt} n_t(x-y)= \Delta_x n_t(x-y)$.

Thanks for any help